# How do I shoo away parrots and/or seagulls?

Tags: paradise-island-2

I have a quest that requires me to shoo away parrots and/or seagulls from guest areas. I see them flying around, but they don't seem to land on anything, and tapping them while they are flying doesn't do anything.

I saw on Facebook that the developers said they should be in trees and you tap the trees to shoo them, but I haven't seen any in my trees. Do I need certain kinds of trees in certain places, or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find the seagulls along the beach.  Their the ones that are landed on the beach.  Click on them to shoo them.  Make sure there aren't any items on the beach, because that can interfere with you clicking them.  The parrots can be found in the clouded areas.  They are nesting in the trees itself and not flying around.  You click on them also to shoo them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to shoo the parrots in Paradise 2. You go to the non built up places (it shows as clouds in the game) and watch for parrots there. They land on trees much more often than on the inhabited areas of the islands, and you can quickly and easily shoo them.